# Не могу "достать" значение из поля MongoDB для последующих операций

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Два дня поисков ничего не дали, считаю, что пора задать вопрос знающим людям. Я только начал изучать метеор и всю его структуру и столкнулся с такой проблемой: у меня есть коллекция в MongoDB, под названием users, там один лишь документ (строка), где есть поле '_id' и мною созданное поле 'money'. В поле 'money' я положил значение 1000. Я благополучно могу выводить это значение на экран с помощью helpers.

```js
import { User } from '../../api/collections.js'
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';

Template.cubegame.helpers ({
 users() {
  return User.find({}); 
 },
});
```

Это все происходит на стороне клиента и поэтому я подключаю константу User для работы с БД из другого файла collections.js, вот его код

```js
export const User = new Meteor.Collection('users');
```

Выводить на экран значение из поля money - да, обновлять значение поля money - да, всё это удается сделать, но я не могу получить значение поля money для записи его в переменную, чтобы использовать это значение как точку старта. К примеру - человек зашел на сайт и хочет приобрести товар за 1200 рублей, а на балансе лишь 1000. Я не могу провести сравнение данных баланса из БД с запросом затрат пользователя, потому что эту самую 1000 из БД я не могу получить именно в формате 1000 для последующих операций.

К слову, мне удалось это сделать в консоли mongo Shell, при помощи такого запроса:

```js
db.users.find()[0].money
```

Если я пытаюсь получить значение через find, я получаю курсор, что с ним делать я не понимаю, т.к если пытаюсь указать ячейку [0], или добавить .money, всегда консоль бьет ошибку по типу "Cannot read property 'money' of undefined". Возможно, я должен это делать на стороне сервера, или я просто не знаю как преобразовать курсор в данные из конкретной ячейки? Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 3):

На стороне клиента функция find не выкачивает результат. Для того, чтобы получить результат операции find нужно вызвать метод fetch. в консоли будут отображаться данные.

Но я вас очень прошу - перенесите потом всякие проверки на backend и вызывайте методы удаленно. Сторона Frontend открыта всем, и свечение лишними данными может кончиться печально.

```js
import { User } from '../../api/collections.js'
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';

Template.cubegame.helpers ({
users() {
    var allUsers = User.find({});
    var fetchedUsers = allUsers.fetch();
    console.log(fetchedUsers);
    if(fetchedUsers.length > 0){
       fetchedUsers.forEach( function(usr){
         console.log("User : ", usr); 
         if(usr.money){
            console.log("User money: ", usr.money);
         }
      })
    }
 return User.find({}); 
},
});
```